# Many-To-Many relationship with filtered view

Tags: hibernate

I have a plant to company relationship that is many-to-many because the plant can produce for multiple companies and the company can have multiple plants. For the application I'm developing we have created a view to filter down the company list on a certain criteria.

When I go to populate my Plant list I get an error as it looks for companies that are in its join table but do not have a record in the filtered company view. Is there a way to set this up so that plants with no companies are not returned or do I need to rework my view setup.

Example:

```
Plant Table
Plant A
Plant B
Plant C

Filtered Company Table View
Company 1
Company 2
Company 3

Join Table
Plant A -> Company 1
Plant A -> Company 2
Plant B -> Company 4
Plant C -> Company 3
Plant C -> Company 4

Output -> error, company 4 does not exist
Desired Output -> Plant A(Company 1,2) - Plant C(Company 3)
```

My entry in the Plant.hbm.xml file.

```
<set name="company" table="plant_company_join_table" schema="myschema" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="plant_id" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
    <many-to-many class="com.redacted.Company">
        <column name="company_id" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So of course I find an answer as soon as I give up and ask the internet. So for those of you in the future who have this problem, here's what I did. Remove the table and schema from the 'set' tag then add a 'subselect' tag that filters the join table by the entries in the company table. Hope this helps!!!

```
<set name="company" lazy="false">
    <subselect>
        select plant_id, company_id from myschema.plant_company_join_table jntbl
        join myschema.company_view using (plant_company_id)
    </subselect>
    <key>
        <column name="plant_id" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
    <many-to-many class="com.redacted.Company">
        <column name="company_id" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```